# Log4ALA doesn't create log on Azure Log Analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have a web API application in C#. I use log4net to log errors. Now I need to log errors also on Azure Log Analytics. To do this I use https://github.com/ptv-logistics/Log4ALA.

I configured correctly my `web.config`:

```
<appender name="Log4ALAAppender" type="Log4ALA.Log4ALAAppender, Log4ALA">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <workspaceId value="#########" />
    <SharedKey value="#########" />
    <logType value="Test" />
    <logMessageToFile value="true"/>
    <batchWaitMaxInSec value="2"/>
</appender>
<logger name="Log4ALALogger" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="Log4ALAAppender" />
</logger>
```

In my C# log service class I tried to send a new log in this way:

```
private static readonly ILog alaLog = LogManager.GetLogger("Log4ALAAppender");

// Other code

alaLog.Debug($"Exception={Exception}; Param1={Param1}; Param2={Param2}");
```

When program execute this line, it creates correctly `log4ALA_error.txt` and `log4ALA_error.info` but nothing was logged.

I tried to use `Log4ALATest` console application from repository and it works fine. So I tried to use in my application `<appSettings>` as did in `Log4ALATest` but, with this configuration, `log4ALA_error.txt` and `log4ALA_error.info` are not created.

What am I doing wrong? There is a known issue in the library with C# MVC?